# Creating subdomains / virtualhost in apache on CentOS

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I used to access my website directly like so:

```
100.100.100.100/project1/public
```

I was also using an edit tool and accessing it like so:

```
100.100.100.100/tool
```

I added a subdomain (dev.domain.com) to my A records and updated my apache httpd.conf file like so:

```
NameVirtualHost         *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.dev.domain.com
    ServerAlias dev.domain.com
    ServerAdmin email@domail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/public
</VirtualHost>
```

and now I can access my website directly by typing my subdomain:  - dev.domain.com.

But since I did that, I cannot access my edit tool the way I used too (100.100.100.100/tool) anymore. It looks like apache is trying to access my website (project1) when I type 100.100.100.100/tool

Is there a way to setup my subdomain so it only access my website located at /var/www/html/project1/public without affecting any other documents I have under /var/www/html/  ???  without affecting, e.g.:

- /var/www/html/tool
- /var/www/html/project2
- /var/www/html/project3

---

I typed in the following command and got:

```
# apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS

httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 100.100.100.100 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   www.dev.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1021)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a vhost for your IP that points to /var/www/html/ as the document root?

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that? Sorry, i'm new to linux and not sure what to try next. thanks

Comment: Try `<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 100.100.100.100
        ServerAdmin email@domail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    </VirtualHost>`
But full disclosure, its been 2 years since I've had to do this, I'm giving you a pointer to try and see if it helps.

Comment: It worked! Thanks @Practically